# How to avoid StackOverFlow in recursion?

Tags: java, exception, recursion, stack-overflow

I need to find the frequency of each character in a `String` using recursion. 
Found this question online and wanted to do this as a challenge.

Have used two variables `'a'` and `'i'`, where `'a'` is used to store the index of the current character in the string that needs to be searched and `'i'` is used to go through the entire string in search of the character that `'a'` has extracted.

*Finding the frequency of each character present in the word.*

```java
import java.util.*;
public class ini {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        recur(0, 0, "Hello how are you", 0);
    }

    static private char m = ' ';

    private static boolean recur(int a, int i, String s, int count) {
        if (s.length() >= 1) {
            if (a < s.length()) {
                m = s.charAt(a);
                if (i < s.length()) {
                    if (s.charAt(a) == s.charAt(i)) {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    recur(a, ++i, s, count);
                }
                i = 0;
                System.out.println(s.charAt(a) + ":" + count);
                s = s.replaceAll(Character.toString(s.charAt(a)), "");
                a += 1;
                count = 0;
            }
            if (a != s.length() - 1) {
                recur(a, i, s, count);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The current output ignores the letter `"w"` altogether

```
H:1
l:2
 :3
o:3
r:1
y:1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at ini.recur(ini.java:26)
at...
```

Comment: `recur(a, i, s, count)` line causes it. The arguments are not changed between the calls. It should probably be `recur(a + 1, i, s, count)`

Comment: yes i did recognise that. i played around with `recur(++a, 0, s, 0)` a lot but didn't get any results.

Comment: @Nexevis yes the code that i have posted was one of the trials i was executing whilst trying to find the correct result hence i have done that. i agree with you that the `if & else` right before the recursion call is not a good practice.

Comment: Using the in built API could also be used. String.toCharArray() into a list. And then using Collections.frequency.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater alright but where am i lacking the logic here. It still wouldnt solve the problem where the above excludes the character 'w' entirely.

Comment: Are you sure that the conditions for updating the indices are correct? Please note that my suggestion was to avoid recursion altogether.

Comment: Using one letter variable names make the code hard to read. I’m guessing what the meaning should be. I would like to read the meaning instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/how-to-count-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that we don't know:

1. Should `h` and `H` be considered only one character?
2. Should you count the spaces? (Programmatically speaking, space is a character)
3. Do you need an improved solution?
4. Are you allowed to do manipulate the initial text?

Some observations:

1. You need to rename your variables better
2. You don't need the static field
3. You don't need the recursive function to be boolean
4. `a` is used only for the identification of the character, and the increment is not needed

Quick solution:

```
private static void recur(int startingIndex, int recursionIndex, String text, int count) {
    if (text.length() >= 1) {
        if (startingIndex < text.length()) {

            char currentCharacter = text.charAt(startingIndex);

            if (recursionIndex < text.length()) {
                if (currentCharacter == text.charAt(recursionIndex)) {
                    count += 1;
                }

                recur(startingIndex, ++recursionIndex, text, count);
            } else {
                System.out.println(currentCharacter + ":" + count);
                text = text.replace(Character.toString(currentCharacter), "");

                recur(0, 0, text, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Improved solution:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recur(0, "Hello how are you", 0);
    }

    private static void recur(int index, String text, int count) {
        if (text.length() >= 1) {
            char currentCharacter = text.charAt(0);

            if (index< text.length()) {
                if (currentCharacter == text.charAt(index)) {
                    count += 1;
                }

                recur(++index, text, count);
            } else {
                System.out.println(currentCharacter + ":" + count);
                text = text.replace(Character.toString(currentCharacter), "");

                recur(0, text, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The optimal solution without modifying the initial text:

```java
private static int recur(char character, String text, int index) {
    if (index >= text.length()) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = text.charAt(index) == character? 1 : 0;
    return count + recur(text, character, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: @lafeo_007 If my answer is good enough, please upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Gosh your code is almost like Elixir thanks bud! I'll be using your code for my final solution. 
My error was quite encapsulated into bad logic, my recursive skills are not the best is what I can conclude. Will work on them, nonetheless thanks a lot @LoolKovsky!

Answer (score 2):

After much tinkering I've figured it out.  Basically you should not increment a.  This will skip over letters and thus remove the line where a is incremented.`a += 1;` Furthermore, with recursion (I was struggling to remember myself) you want to be careful how you call the function you are in.  If you don't make the recursive call as the last step (tail recursion), you will enter an infinite loop for various reasons here.  All you need to do is add a return statement before the first recursive call and you will have solved it like so.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class ini {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        recur(0, 0, "Hello how are you", 0);
    }

    static private char m = ' ';

    private static boolean recur(int a, int i, String s, int count) {
        if (s.length() >= 1) {
            if (a < s.length()) {
                m = s.charAt(a);
                if (i < s.length()) {
                    if (s.charAt(a) == s.charAt(i)) {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    //Added crucial return statement
                    return recur(a, ++i, s, count);
                }
                i = 0;
                System.out.println(s.charAt(a) + ":" + count);
                s = s.replaceAll(Character.toString(s.charAt(a)), "");
                //removed a += 1;
                count = 0;
            }
            if (a != s.length() - 1) {
                recur(a, i, s, count);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
H:1
e:2
l:2
o:3
 :3
h:1
w:1
a:1
r:1
y:1
```

Here is a link about tail vs. head recursion : [Tail vs. Head Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426688/the-difference-between-head-tail-recursion)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks a ton!
After seeing the more recent answers I have cleaned the code quite a bit removing the unnecessary `boolean` return statements. Thank you for the link, will have a look!

Comment: Although there is still one error in both our codes! 
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?
`

Our coded cannot work with ??, !! or other such characters!

Comment: Np, but interesting point, I'll look into that and report back to you!

Answer (score 2):

My approach is slightly different from yours but you might find it interesting.
In my approach I am removing the character and checking the difference in the length of String. The change in length would be the times that character repeated. Rest is explained in the code.

```
public class CharactersFrequency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharactersFrequency cF = new CharactersFrequency();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // I generated a sting with 1000 characters from a website
        cF.frequencyOfCharacters("a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Runtime: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
    }

    private void frequencyOfCharacters(String input) {
        CharactersFrequency cF = new CharactersFrequency();
        cF.frequencyOfCharactersRec(input, input.charAt(0) + "");
    }

    public void frequencyOfCharactersRec(String input, String currentChar) {
        // If only one char is left
        if (input.length() <= 1) {
            System.out.println(currentChar + ": 1");
        } else {
            // Checking Initial length and saving it
            int inputOldLength = input.length();
            // Removing the char whose frequency I am checking
            input = input.replace(currentChar, "");
            // Checking new length
            int inputNewLength = input.length();
            // The difference between length should be the number of times that char 
            // repeated
            System.out.println(currentChar + " : " + (inputOldLength - inputNewLength));
            // In some cases after replace function the string becomes empty
            // thus charAt(0) gives an error
            if (inputNewLength > 0) {
                frequencyOfCharactersRec(input, input.charAt(0) + "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a : 2
  : 8
q : 1
u : 2
i : 1
c : 1
k : 1
b : 1
r : 2
o : 4
w : 1
n : 1
f : 1
x : 1
j : 1
m : 1
p : 1
s : 1
v : 1
e : 2
t : 1
h : 1
l : 1
z : 1
y : 1
d : 1
g: 1
Runtime: 3 ms
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote your answer but you have to keep in mind that he asked a specific question for his specific problem and you came up with a totally different solution which was not solving the initial problem

Comment: Fair enough. I was expecting your answer to be accepted moreover since user said "Found this question online and wanted to do this as a challenge." so I though he wouldn't mind. I have voted your answer so it would be on top since it exactly answers what user asked.

Comment: @Goion you got me right I wrote that, especially so that I can subtly show that I am open to new kinds of methods of solving this question. 
I loved this approach, however, the sample `String` you provided was quite much. Thanks a ton, although your method is similar, it's just you have dissected compounds lines of code into simpler ways! Thanks again...!

Comment: @LoolKovsky Didn't downvote. Anyways I have changed the string to a smaller one so the code is easier to read.

Comment: haha much better than that SHA like text. For the sake of this community and for @LoolKovsky 's answer being more precise and crisp I have marked his answer to be the final solution.

Comment: @Goion our codes dont work ??, !! in the end of the String though! Have to change the `replaceAll()` to `replace()` for that!

Comment: @lafeo_007 `replaceAll()` takes regular expression so characters such as `?` etc... that have special meaning in Regex messes it up. If you want to use replace all change it like this. `text.replaceAll("["+Character.toString(currentCharacter)+"]", "");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197697/discussion-between-goion-and-lafeo-007).